# Understanding DataContext when passing parameter to user control property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have built a `UserControl` containing a `TreeView` where each node contains a bunch of controls.
Simplified version of the tree's code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyTestWPF.MyTree"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTestWPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="MyTreeUserControl">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTreeNode}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyTreeProp, ElementName=MyTreeUserControl}" />
</UserControl>
```

The control's codebehind only has a simple `DependencyProperty` for the `MyTreeProp` property created with the `propdp` snippet.

I then call the control like so:

```
<local:MyTree MyTreeModel="{Binding Path=MyData}" />
```

And here's the parent view's `DataContext` with `MyData`:

```
this.DataContext = new {
    MyData = new List<MyTreeNode>() {
        new MyTreeNode() {
            Name = "1",
            Nodes = new MyTreeNode[] {
                new MyTreeNode() { Name= "2" }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The `MyTreeNode` is simply:

```
public class MyTreeNode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyTreeNode[] Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

My question is about passing data into the `MyTree` control's `MyTreeProp`.
I initially tried to set the `ItemsSource`'s binding without the `ElementName`, and setting `MyTree`'s `DataContext` to `this` in the constructor, but that threw an exception:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
'MyData' property not found on 'object' ''MyTree' (Name='MyTreeUserControl')'. BindingExpression:Path=MyData;
DataItem='MyTree' (Name='MyTreeUserControl');
target element is 'MyTree' (Name='MyTreeUserControl');
target property is 'MyTreeProp' (type 'List`1')
```

Why?

- What am I misunderstanding about how the view is attempting to read the `DataContext`?
- Why does it seem from the error that it is searching for `MyData` on the UserControl? Or am I misreading that?
- Is there really no way to pass the value to the UserControl's property, and then use it without the need to reference the `UserControl.Name` in each and every element that needs to read it?

*--Edit--*
Based on the comments, I understand that setting `DataContext` directly is wrong... but that still leaves the question - what is the correct way to access the UserControl's properties? Does it really require setting a name to the `UserControl` tag, and then explicitly referencing it by name whenever I need to access the property?

Comment: `'MyData' property not found on 'object' ''MyTree' (Name='MyTreeUserControl')` means that you have explicitly set the UserControl's DataContext. You must not do that.

Comment: If that is the case, why are half of the examples I've seen on stack overflow explicitly setting `this.DataContext = this;` in the constructor?

Comment: These examples are all wrong, sorry. People who recommend it do not know what they are talking about. Setting `DataContext = this;` (or setting it to some private view model) effectively prevents that `MyTreeModel="{Binding Path=MyData}"` works as intended.

Comment: Instead of `ItemsSource="{Binding MyTreeProp, ElementName=MyTreeUserControl}"` you may write `ItemsSource="{Binding MyTreeProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. Thus you avoid to have a generated `MyTreeUserControl` field in your UserControl class.

Comment: I think I understand. If I want to do what I'm looking to do, I need to actually use a `Model` object and set that. It will then be passed around my `UserControl` as `DataContext` automatically. I was expecting some more simple way to access the `View`'s properties from the `View`... but I understand that this was not a well-founded expectation.